# Find a New Line character in a Text File and clear it using Windows Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, window

I would need a Windows Batch Script to find an incorrect "Newline" Character in a file and delete it. In practice, the file size is huge and there are multiple lines with such "NewLine" characters. Hence editting is problematic. Also if I do the editting using Notepad, with Wordwrap functionality ON, it induces more NewLine characters. As of now I am doing it through Textpad applciation, but that too is a manual workaround and is prone to errors.
Hence I would like to seek your advice if this can be done through Windows batch script.

================

## Sample Text

1,2,3,

4,5,6,

7,8,

9,

10,11,

12,

13,14,15,

16,17,

18,

19,20,21,

## 22,23,24,

================

## Desired Output

1,2,3,

4,5,6,

7,8,9,

10,11,12,

13,14,15,

16,17,18,

19,20,21,

## 22,23,24,

The script doesn't work if i mix match characters and numbers. The input file in practice will be a csv extract from a database, which can have datatypes like Varchar2, Number, Float, etc in each column separated by a comma. How can i make use of that script in such case.

## Sample 2

123,abc,hscs,456,adf,,

321,cba,hcdfs,4321,wqe,12,

213,bac,

hfc,145,quf,134,

457,dsxa,

dfcx,4567,hgpl,786,

879,cxd,yht,684,ytre,,

## Desired Output

123,abc,hscs,456,adf,,

321,cba,hcdfs,4321,wqe,12,

213,bac,hfc,145,quf,134,

457,dsxa,dfcx,4567,hgpl,786,

879,cxd,yht,684,ytre,,

Thanks

Comment: Can someone please help with the second test case for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A file format like this:

```
1,2,3,
4,5,6,
7,8,
9,
10,11,
12,
13,14,15,
16,17,
18,
19,20,21,
22,23,24,
```

will become this:

```
1,2,3,
4,5,6,
7,8,9,
10,11,12,
13,14,15,
16,17,18,
19,20,21,
22,23,24,
```

with this code:

```
type "file.txt" |repl "(^[0-9]*,[0-9]*,)\r\n" "$1" mx >"newfile.txt"
```

The code above uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

repl.bat is very robust and very quick on large files, compared to plain batch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the above. However if I change the input string and add some characters, the script fails.